# How to create Tkinter Buttons with a For loop?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a basic Gmail client, but I seem to be having issues with dynamically creating the Tkinter Buttons. In my class `Main_Window`, I have a method called `mainFun`. In this method is this code, which attempts to create 11 buttons numbered 1-11.

```
for i in range(1,11):

    self.newmessage = Button(self, text = "%d" % i)
    Main_Window.entryFrame.append(self.newmessage)
```

Annoyingly, I get an error when I run my code.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
==== No Subprocess ====
>>> 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/media/PI_USB/Email Send/Email Send GUI V2.py", line 111, in remember_Authen
    self.authen_credits()
  File "/media/PI_USB/Email Send/Email Send GUI V2.py", line 101, in authen_credits
    app = Main_Window()
  File "/media/PI_USB/Email Send/Email Send GUI V2.py", line 225, in __init__
    self.mainFun()
  File "/media/PI_USB/Email Send/Email Send GUI V2.py", line 281, in mainFun
    Main_Window.entryFrame.append(self.newmessage)
AttributeError: class Main_Window has no attribute 'entryFrame'
```

If it is needed, here is a pastebin link to the rest of my code:

http://pastebin.com/7J9newip

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

- `Main_Window.entryFrame` seems typo of `self.entryFrame`.
- `Tkinter.Frame` does not have `append`: To append a widget to frame, when create a widget with frame as parent. Then call `widget.pack(..)` or `widget.grid(..)`.

---

```
for i in range(1,11):
    self.newmessage = Button(self.entryFrame, text="%d" % i)
    self.newmessage.pack()
```